# Spring platform-bom and dependencyManagment

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to refactor a quite-complex maven project, with a parent project and sub-projects. It uses some Spring Boot and Spring dependencies. In the parent pom, only a few dependencies are defined under `<dependencies>` (global dependencies inherited in all sub-projects). The rest is defined under `<dependencyManagement>`, in order to define a version for the whole project. Each sub-project defines its own `<dependencies>`, without setting a version.

But the version management is messy; in parent pom, each dependency version is defined with a global property.

I would like to use a platform-bom: I've tried a parent platform-bom.
Works for `<dependencies>` but not for `<dependencyManagement>`.

In sub-projects, versions are not defined; is there a solution?

```
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar is missing
```

EDIT

Parent pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Parent Project</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.io.version>2.0.3.RELEASE</spring.io.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.3.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>io.spring.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>platform-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <!--<relativePath />-->
    </parent>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.0</version>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${spring.boot.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- devtools (ressources hot swap) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <!--<version>${spring.boot.version}</version>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <!--<version>${spring.boot.version}</version>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Spring -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
                <version>4.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- JPA support -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- H2 database -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.191</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Project sub modules -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
                <artifactId>myapp-common</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-core</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

            <!-- Other -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.1</version>
            </dependency>

    <!-- And some more dependencies... -->

    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
        <module>myapp-common</module>
        <module>myapp-core</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

One of the subproject

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>myapp-core</artifactId>
    <description>Core</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myapp</groupId>
        <artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>

<!--        JPA support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        H2 database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<!--        MySQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Can you please post the parent POM and a child POM? I can help if you do that.

Comment: done with some anonymization :)

Comment: seems that when i'm defining spring dependencies ONLY in modules, it works..

Comment: I copied and pasted those POMS (removing the module you didn't include and adding a missing XML tag) and was able to build, did you modify them after to found the problem?

Comment: the problem was that spring dependencies were defined in dependencyManagement of parent, which forces to define a version. If version is no defined in parent, it has to be in child poms. The solution is to remove spring dependencies of dependencyManagment, and only declare them in child. This way, to version is provided by platform-bom. Set a dependency in parent dependencyManagement overrides the platform-bom.

Comment: I will post a solution from work this week :)